# jQuery carousel slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on jQuery carousel. Here is my code:

```js
  // CAROUSEL
  $('#left-arrow').click(previousSlide);
  $('#right-arrow').click(nextSlide);

function nextSlide() {
    var $currentSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:first');
    var width = $currentSlide.width();
    var $lastSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:last')
    $currentSlide.animate({ 'margin-left': -width }, 1000, function() {
        $currentSlide.remove().css({ 'margin-left': '0px' });
        $lastSlide.after($currentSlide);
    });
  }

  function previousSlide() {
    var $currentSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:first');
   var width = $currentSlide.width();
    var $last = $('#carousel .slide-image:last');
    $last.remove().css({ 'margin-left': -width });
    $currentSlide.before($last);
    $last.animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 1000);
  }
```

```css
/* CAROUSEL */
#slide1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#slide2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#slide3 {
  background-color: magenta;
}


#carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
}

.slide-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}


.arrow {
  width: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#right-arrow {
  right: 30px;
}

#left-arrow {
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="carousel">
      <div class="arrow" id="left-arrow">L</div>
      <div class="arrow" id="right-arrow">R</div>

      <div class="slide-image" id="slide1">
      </div>

      <div class="slide-image" id="slide2">
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide-image" id="slide3">
      </div>
    </section>
```

The problem is that it is acting differently for left and right side. If you click left side multiple times, it will just move the slider number of times, according on the number of clicks at once. If you however click multiple times on the right side, it will always move only once. That is because the current slide is being pushed before the last slide and there is no slide yet. However I would like it to act the same as the left side so it should be able to move multiple times.

How could I achieve that behaviour?

Comment: Because when you click R twice quickly, the value of `var $currentSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:first');` in the `nextSlide()` function will be the same value, because the slide is not removed until the animation is complete.

Comment: Thanks! @2pha what would be the best way of solving it?

Comment: Depends if you want the user to be able to click before an animation is complete or not. If you want the user to have to wait until the animation is finished before they can click again, you could just have a variable that tracks if animation is happening or not, then check that in the nextSlide and previousSlide functions.

Comment: @2pha I want the user to be able to click before the animation finish more. Just like in the previous slide case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [stoping](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) the current animation and move to next slide.

You can use a variable like `nextAnimation` to check if the animation is still playing.

```js
// CAROUSEL
  $('#left-arrow').click(previousSlide);
  $('#right-arrow').click(nextSlide);
  
  var nextAnimation = false;

function nextSlide() {
    var $currentSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:first');
    var width = $currentSlide.width();
    var $lastSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:last');
    if(nextAnimation) {
      $currentSlide.stop();
      $currentSlide.remove().css({ 'margin-left': '0px' });
      $lastSlide.after($currentSlide);
      $currentSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:first');
      width = $currentSlide.width();
      $lastSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:last');
    }
    nextAnimation = true;
    $currentSlide.animate({ 'margin-left': -width }, 1000, function() {
        $currentSlide.remove().css({ 'margin-left': '0px' });
        $lastSlide.after($currentSlide);
        nextAnimation = false;
    });
  }

  function previousSlide() {
    var $currentSlide = $('#carousel .slide-image:first');
   var width = $currentSlide.width();
    var $last = $('#carousel .slide-image:last');
    $last.remove().css({ 'margin-left': -width });
    $currentSlide.before($last);
    $last.animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 1000);
  }
```

```css
/* CAROUSEL */
#slide1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#slide2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#slide3 {
  background-color: magenta;
}


#carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
}

.slide-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}


.arrow {
  width: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#right-arrow {
  right: 30px;
}

#left-arrow {
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="carousel">
      <div class="arrow" id="left-arrow">L</div>
      <div class="arrow" id="right-arrow">R</div>

      <div class="slide-image" id="slide1">1
      </div>

      <div class="slide-image" id="slide2">2
      </div>
      
      <div class="slide-image" id="slide3">3
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: this is perfect!